# How to get validation messages for all nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given this models:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

I want to get the validation message for each nested `Bar` I create, because ...

```rb
Foo.create(bars_attributes: [, { title: nil }, { title: "foo" }, { title: nil }])
```

... results in `@errors=[#<ActiveModel::NestedError attribute=bars.title, type=blank, options={}>]`, but I don't know which records (in this case, records at index 0 and 2) have failed. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Break it down. Instead of trying to do everything in one command (which can only give you a success/failure response), try something like this (assumes it's being passed the details of your required Bar records in the params as an Enumerable (i.e. array or hash)).

```rb
@foo = foo.create(field_1: foo_params[:field_1], field_2: foo_params[:field_2])
_failed_bar_records = []
foo_params[:bar_data].each do |_bar_data|
  _bar = Bar.new(foo_id: @foo.id, title: _bar_data[:title])
  _failed_bar_records.push(_bar_data[:title]) unless _bar.save
end
```

Then, you'll have an array `_failed_bar_records` that contains data about each failed record. You could obviously push more to this array, like the actual error message.

Comment: Hm, I wanted to avoid this, since this is just a very basic example which I've created for this question. In my real application, this is part of a huge abstraction around a GraphQL API

Comment: It's not really any more complex than the one-line version: you could easily fit it into 2 lines (one to create the Foo record and then one to iterate over the related Bar records): `foo_params[:bar_data].each { |b| _fail.push(b[:title]) unless Bar.new(foo_id: @foo.id, title: b[:title]).save }`. Logically, you're doing the same job in either case - it's just a matter of how you're communicating it to Rails. This is just more explicit and hence informative.

Comment: But I don‘t know the model of my nested attributes. It‘s a generic mutation class, which just forwards all fields/attributes to the base model. I would have to remove a lot of logic to write explicit stuff like Bar.new :/

Comment: Well, that's outside my experience so I'm going to be no help to you, I'm afraid! 

Answer (score 0):

you could dig down to nested record's errors instead of checking the parent record's errors

```rb
@problem = Problem.new(problem_params)

@problem.solutions
# [<Solution:0x0000565379c46170 id: nil, description: "a solution", problem_id: nil, ...>,
#  <Solution:0x0000565379cc2248 id: nil, description: "", problem_id: nil, ...>]

@problem.save

@problem.errors
# <ActiveModel::Errors:..
# @base= <Problem:0x0000565379c33890 ...>,
# @errors=[
#  <ActiveModel::NestedError attribute=solutions.description, type=blank, options={}>
# ]>

@problem.solutions.map(&:errors)
# [
#   <ActiveModel::Errors:...
#    @base= <Solution:0x0000565379c46170 ...>,
#    @errors=[]>,
#
#   <ActiveModel::Errors:...
#    @base= <Solution:0x0000565379cc2248 ...>,
#    @errors=[
#     <ActiveModel::Error attribute=description, type=blank, options={}>
#    ]>
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on [Lam Phan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69717237/3739756), validation errors for each child are accessible as a property of the child itself.

```rb
foo = Foo.create(bars_attributes: [{title: nil},{ title: "foo" }, {title: nil}])
=> #<Foo:0x0000559761e83c50 id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

foo.bars.map(&:errors).map(&:details)
=> [{:title=>[{:error=>:blank}]}, {}, {:title=>[{:error=>:blank}]}]

foo.bars.map(&:errors).map(&:messages)
=> [{:title=>["can't be blank"]}, {}, {:title=>["can't be blank"]}]
```

---

On a different, arguably less elegant path, with a custom method for validation, it's possible to cycle on the received nested records, adding an error that registers the index of the failing ones.

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
  validate :bars_validator

  def bars_validator
    children_valid = bars.map(&:valid?).all?
    bars.each_with_index do |b,i| 
      b.errors.each do |err|
        msg = "#{i}: #{err.attribute} #{err.message}"
        errors.add(:bars, msg, index: i, src: err)
      end
    end
    children_valid
  end
end
```

The index is then retrieved through errors.details

```rb
foo = Foo.create(bars_attributes: [{ title: nil }, { title: "foo" }, { title: nil }])
=> #<Foo:0x00005583f6607a50 id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

foo.errors.details
=>
{:"bars.title"=>[{:error=>:blank}],
 :bars=>
  [{:error=>"0: title can't be blank", :index=>0, :src=>#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=title, type=blank, options={}>},
   {:error=>"2: title can't be blank", :index=>2, :src=>#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=title, type=blank, options={}>}]}
```